# Wice_Grid gem having issues in export CSV with Rails 7.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-csv, wice-grid

We are working on a project that is migrating to Rails 7; we had a wice-grid gem working for Rails 2 but with Rails 7 we are not getting export functionality working. Is there any documentation or any change in wice_grid that defines any difference between Rails 5 and Rails 7 working?

The Export CSV icon doesn't appear at all on the bottom of gird

I tried searching for wice grid export csv issue for rails 7 but could not found any such Stackoverflow question that belongs to this particular problem

Comment: The last time wice_grid was updated was for Rails 4. Time to move on.

Comment: Hi @dbugger thanks for the reply. Would you please suggest any recent gem compatible with Rails 7 and has Export CSV functionality too along with other gird functions like sorting and pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I'm impressed that only export csv is not working.
The main difference is that wice_grid was made to properly work with Turbolinks wich is not present on Rails v7 it was replaced with Turbo. Turbolinks is no longer under active development from [github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks).

I highly recoment the switch to [bogdan/datagrid](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid) wich is the closest aprouch to u guys besides wice_grid and u will be able to make the rework reusing the outdated code like custom filter from helpers and html blocks at columns. The tables layout can also be modfied to look like wicegrid